# Someone clones my web-site. How to know who

Tags: duplicate-content, copy

My problem is someone copied my site. I have already 2 duplicates of my site. Is any chance to know who and how do that? My web-site based on tilda.cc.

Comment: It is usually pretty hard to figure out who clones a website and it probably isn't all that actionable if you were to find out as they are likely they are based in another country.  It is usually easier to focus on making your website harder to clone and ensuring that everybody knows that your original is authoritative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult game of wack-a-mole and it is nowhere near foolproof.

There are a at least a couple of ways - in principle - this can be attacked, but multiple jurisdictions and laws make it tricky and maybe expensive.

The obvious tools at your disposal is to find their hosting provider and provide them a DMCA or equivalent notice.  Most developed western countries have  a variant which gives you some pull - but good luck dealing with a developing country.

You can likewise - and maybe with more success - report it to Google who may remove the bogus copies under the same laws - https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en

Comment: Ok, thank your for your advise. They use cloudfare`s domain. I`ll try to write them

Answer (score 0):

you may use some free duplicate checker like DupliChecker and Siteliner. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok, And If I find who did that, what should I do, because google analitics and etc show me, that part of my traffic sends there. How to block that clones?

Comment: And also, It wasnt copy my content someone dublicated the whole my website. I can not insert here link to my site, because moderator deleted it.